# Value error while using datetime.datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I want to covert a string item to the datetime format that I require.

The string item is this : `'3/27/2013 2:54:00 PM'`

My code is as follows: `map(datetime.datetime.strptime,'3/27/2013 2:54:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')`

I get the following error : `stray % in format '%'`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you use map, you can just use strptime on that string, worked for me

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('3/27/2013 2:54:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
print(dt)
```

Comment: I wanted to apply it to an entire list. However, your suggestion works too and I can implement this method. Thank you